# Less clumsy way of grouping by month?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm grouping data by month, and the result should be of type `Date`.

The example I'm posting currently works, but I find it so long and clumsy since I have to parse the final date to be used as grouping.

In any case, this is the whole script:

```
declare @table table
(
    ReportDate date,
    Sales int
)
insert into @table
select '11/5/2018', 1 union 
select '11/8/2018', 3 union 
select '3/5/2019', 2 union 
select '3/8/2019', 6 union 
select '4/1/2019', 5

select 
cast(CAST(MONTH(reportdate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/1/' + CAST(year(reportdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) as date) as 'MonthOfYear', 
SUM(sales) as 'sales' FROM @table
group by 
cast(CAST(MONTH(reportdate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/1/' + CAST(year(reportdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) as date)
order by cast(CAST(MONTH(reportdate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/1/' + CAST(year(reportdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) as date)
```

Which returns:

```
MonthOfYear    sales
2018-11-01     4
2019-03-01     8
2019-04-01     5
```

The result is correct, but I find this very clumsy and very long. Is there a more compact way of grouping by month where the result is of type `Date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reporting based on dates becomes a *lot* easier and faster if you use a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). A Calendar table contains entries for all dates for the next eg 50 years, with explicit columns for year, quarter, semester, month, day in month, day in year, week day, week number etc. The `Date` is the primary key and the rest of the columns are indexed based on reporting needs.

Assuming you create a table with an extra column for the StartOfMonth for each date, the query could become as simple as :

```
SELECT StartOfMonth,sum(Sales)
FROM @table inner join Calendar on Calendar.Date=ReportDate
GROUP BY StartOfMonth
```

Comment: I have a Calendar table. My initial thought was to format to `date` and then join with Calendar table.

Comment: But that makes sense. Do an initial join with the Calendar table and then group the Calendar table instead.

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf add the formatted text as an extra column in the Calendar table. The storage cost will be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

A common way to change a date to the start of the month in 2008 is using `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` against the date `0` (aka 19000101):

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,T.ReportDate),0)) AS MonthDate,
       SUM(Sales) AS TotalSales
FROM @table T
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,T.ReportDate),0);
```

If you're using 2012+ (which you really should be, as 2008 is now **completely** unsupported), you can use `EOMONTH` and `DATEADD`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(T.ReportDate,-1)) AS MonthDate,
       SUM(Sales) AS TotalSales
FROM @table T
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(T.ReportDate,-1));
```

This has the advantage of not having to `CAST`/`CONVERT` the expression back to a `date` (As `0` or `'19000101'` would be interpreted as a `datetime`).

*Helpful tip. When supplying dates, please avoid using ambiguous formats. The results I get are **not** the same as your expected results, as a date like `'11/5/2018'` means 11 May 2018. Considering all your dates are valid in both the `d/M/yyyy` and `M/d/yyyy` format as well, that makes it even more confusing. When supplying dates for SQL Server questions, the `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` are the best formats, as they are unambigious.*

Answer (score 1):

The `+'-01'` is optional

```
Select MonthOfYear = convert(varchar(7),ReportDate,120)+'-01'
      ,Sales       = sum(Sales)
 From  @table
 Group BY convert(varchar(7),ReportDate,120)
```

**Returns**

```
MonthOfYear  Sales
2018-11-01   4
2019-03-01   8
2019-04-01   5
```

> **EDIT**

Rather than `convert()`, you can use the implicit conversion and use

```
left(ReportDate,7)
```

Comment: And what format does implicit conversion use? Is it consistent? Is it documented?

Comment: @SMor That would be a string,   Take a peek at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast(yyyymm + '01' as date) as MonthOfYear,
       SUM(sales) as sales
from @table cross apply (select convert(char(6),ReportDate, 112) as yyyymm)a
group by yyyymm
order by MonthOfYear;
```

Comment: You should use the column alias in your order by instead of the ordinal position. Using ordinal position in an order by is challenging for a number of reasons. But this definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are after format:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '10/01/2011';  
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-US' ) AS 'US English Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-gb' ) AS 'Great Britain English Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'de-de' ) AS 'German Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'zh-cn' ) AS 'Simplified Chinese (PRC) Result';

SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'en-US' ) AS 'US English Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'en-gb' ) AS 'Great Britain English Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'de-de' ) AS 'German Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'zh-cn' ) AS 'Chinese (Simplified PRC) Result';
```

More details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but `FORMAT` does not exist in `sql server 2008`. I tagged the question `sql-server-2008` when I asked the question.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Gonna think about it.

Comment: No problem. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I'd say inline function is the way to go or another reason to upgrade the box.

Comment: `FORMAT` is also an awfully slow function and best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I'll see @Panagiotis Kanavos' Calendar Table and raise you a ***Virtual Index***. Using rangeAB (DDL below) you can group/sort/Aggregate/order/de-duplicate/etc *without creating an index*.

```
-- Your data (no index)
declare @table table
(
    ReportDate date,
    Sales int
)
insert @table VALUES ('11/5/2018',1),('11/8/2018',3),('3/5/2019',2),('3/8/2019',6),('4/1/2019',5);

-- Sortless Grouping/Ordering/Aggregating without an Index (or Hashing)
SELECT
  MonthOfYear = DATEADD(DAY,-(DAY(MAX(Dt))-1),MAX(Dt)),
  Sales       = SUM(Sales)
FROM (SELECT startdate = MIN(t.ReportDate), enddate = MAX(t.ReportDate) FROM @table AS t) AS D
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    MonthId = r.RN,
    Dt      = dt.D,
    Yr      = YEAR(dt.D),
    Mo      = MONTH(dt.D)
  FROM        (VALUES(DATEDIFF(MONTH,D.startdate,D.enddate)))       AS f(DD)
  CROSS APPLY dbo.rangeAB(0,ABS(f.DD),1,0)                        AS r
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(MONTH,r.RN*SIGN(f.DD),D.startdate))) AS dt(D)
) AS f
JOIN     @table AS t ON f.Mo = MONTH(t.ReportDate) AND f.Yr = YEAR(t.ReportDate)
GROUP BY f.MonthId
ORDER BY f.MonthId;
```

**Returns:**

```
MonthOfYear Sales
----------- -----------
2018-11-01  4
2019-03-01  8
2019-04-01  5
```

... and the execution plan:

[image]
Look Ma ^^^ no sort!

**RangeAB DDL:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.rangeAB
(
  @low  bigint, 
  @high bigint, 
  @gap  bigint,
  @row1 bit
)
/****************************************************************************************
[Purpose]:
 Creates up to 531,441,000,000 sequentia1 integers numbers beginning with @low and ending 
 with @high. Used to replace iterative methods such as loops, cursors and recursive CTEs 
 to solve SQL problems. Based on Itzik Ben-Gan's getnums function with some tweeks and 
 enhancements and added functionality. The logic for getting rn to begin at 0 or 1 is 
 based comes from Jeff Moden's fnTally function. 

 The name range because it's similar to clojure's range function. The name "rangeAB" as 
 used because "range" is a reserved SQL keyword.

[Author]: Alan Burstein

[Compatibility]: 
 SQL Server 2008+ and Azure SQL Database

[Syntax]:
 SELECT r.RN, r.OP, r.N1, r.N2
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(@low,@high,@gap,@row1) AS r;

[Parameters]:
 @low  = a bigint that represents the lowest value for n1.
 @high = a bigint that represents the highest value for n1.
 @gap  = a bigint that represents how much n1 and n2 will increase each row; @gap also
         represents the difference between n1 and n2.
 @row1 = a bit that represents the first value of rn. When @row = 0 then rn begins
         at 0, when @row = 1 then rn will begin at 1.

[Returns]:
 Inline Table Valued Function returns:
 rn = bigint; a row number that works just like T-SQL ROW_NUMBER() except that it can 
      start at 0 or 1 which is dictated by @row1.
 op = bigint; returns the "opposite number that relates to rn. When rn begins with 0 and
      ends with 10 then 10 is the opposite of 0, 9 the opposite of 1, etc. When rn begins
      with 1 and ends with 5 then 1 is the opposite of 5, 2 the opposite of 4, etc...
 n1 = bigint; a sequential number starting at the value of @low and incrimentingby the
      value of @gap until it is less than or equal to the value of @high.
 n2 = bigint; a sequential number starting at the value of @low+@gap and  incrimenting 
      by the value of @gap.

[Dependencies]:
N/A

[Developer Notes]:

 1. The lowest and highest possible numbers returned are whatever is allowable by a 
    bigint. The function, however, returns no more than 531,441,000,000 rows (8100^3). 
 2. @gap does not affect rn, rn will begin at @row1 and increase by 1 until the last row
    unless its used in a query where a filter is applied to rn.
 3. @gap must be greater than 0 or the function will not return any rows.
 4. Keep in mind that when @row1 is 0 then the highest row-number will be the number of
    rows returned minus 1
 5. If you only need is a sequential set beginning at 0 or 1 then, for best performance
    use the RN column. Use N1 and/or N2 when you need to begin your sequence at any 
    number other than 0 or 1 or if you need a gap between your sequence of numbers. 
 6. Although @gap is a bigint it must be a positive integer or the function will
    not return any rows.
 7. The function will not return any rows when one of the following conditions are true:
      * any of the input parameters are NULL
      * @high is less than @low 
      * @gap is not greater than 0
    To force the function to return all NULLs instead of not returning anything you can
    add the following code to the end of the query:

      UNION ALL 
      SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
      WHERE NOT (@high&@low&@gap&@row1 IS NOT NULL AND @high >= @low AND @gap > 0)

    This code was excluded as it adds a ~5% performance penalty.
 8. There is no performance penalty for sorting by rn ASC; there is a large performance 
    penalty for sorting in descending order WHEN @row1 = 1; WHEN @row1 = 0
    If you need a descending sort the use op in place of rn then sort by rn ASC. 

Best Practices:
--===== 1. Using RN (rownumber)
 -- (1.1) The best way to get the numbers 1,2,3...@high (e.g. 1 to 5):
 SELECT RN FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,5,1,1);
 -- (1.2) The best way to get the numbers 0,1,2...@high-1 (e.g. 0 to 5):
 SELECT RN FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,5,1,0);

--===== 2. Using OP for descending sorts without a performance penalty
 -- (2.1) The best way to get the numbers 5,4,3...@high (e.g. 5 to 1):
 SELECT op FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,5,1,1) ORDER BY rn ASC;
 -- (2.2) The best way to get the numbers 0,1,2...@high-1 (e.g. 5 to 0):
 SELECT op FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,6,1,0) ORDER BY rn ASC;

--===== 3. Using N1
 -- (3.1) To begin with numbers other than 0 or 1 use N1 (e.g. -3 to 3):
 SELECT N1 FROM dbo.rangeAB(-3,3,1,1);
 -- (3.2) ROW_NUMBER() is built in. If you want a ROW_NUMBER() include RN:
 SELECT RN, N1 FROM dbo.rangeAB(-3,3,1,1);
 -- (3.3) If you wanted a ROW_NUMBER() that started at 0 you would do this:
 SELECT RN, N1 FROM dbo.rangeAB(-3,3,1,0);

--===== 4. Using N2 and @gap
 -- (4.1) To get 0,10,20,30...100, set @low to 0, @high to 100 and @gap to 10:
 SELECT N1 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,100,10,1);
 -- (4.2) Note that N2=N1+@gap; this allows you to create a sequence of ranges.
 --       For example, to get (0,10),(10,20),(20,30).... (90,100):
 SELECT N1, N2 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,90,10,1);
 -- (4.3) Remember that a rownumber is included and it can begin at 0 or 1:
 SELECT RN, N1, N2 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,90,10,1);

[Examples]:
--===== 1. Generating Sample data (using rangeAB to create "dummy rows")
 -- The query below will generate 10,000 ids and random numbers between 50,000 and 500,000
 SELECT
   someId    = r.rn,
   someNumer = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%450000)+50001 
 FROM rangeAB(1,10000,1,1) r;

--===== 2. Create a series of dates; rn is 0 to include the first date in the series
 DECLARE @startdate DATE = '20180101', @enddate DATE = '20180131';

 SELECT r.rn, calDate = DATEADD(dd, r.rn, @startdate)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(1, DATEDIFF(dd,@startdate,@enddate),1,0) r;
 GO

--===== 3. Splitting (tokenizing) a string with fixed sized items
 -- given a delimited string of identifiers that are always 7 characters long
 DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'A601225,B435223,G008081,R678567';

 SELECT
   itemNumber = r.rn, -- item's ordinal position 
   itemIndex  = r.n1, -- item's position in the string (it's CHARINDEX value)
   item       = SUBSTRING(@string, r.n1, 7) -- item (token)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(1, LEN(@string), 8,1)  r;
 GO

--===== 4. Splitting (tokenizing) a string with random delimiters
 DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'ABC123,999F,XX,9994443335';

 SELECT
   itemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY r.rn), -- item's ordinal position 
   itemIndex  = r.n1+1, -- item's position in the string (it's CHARINDEX value)
   item       = SUBSTRING
               (
                 @string,
                 r.n1+1,
                 ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',',@string,r.n1+1),0)-r.n1-1, 8000)
               ) -- item (token)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,DATALENGTH(@string),1,1) r
 WHERE SUBSTRING(@string,r.n1,1) = ',' OR r.n1 = 0;
 -- logic borrowed from: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

--===== 5. Grouping by a weekly intervals
 -- 5.1. how to create a series of start/end dates between @startDate & @endDate
 DECLARE @startDate DATE = '1/1/2015', @endDate DATE = '2/1/2015';
 SELECT 
   WeekNbr   = r.RN,
   WeekStart = DATEADD(DAY,r.N1,@StartDate), 
   WeekEnd   = DATEADD(DAY,r.N2-1,@StartDate)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,datediff(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate),7,1) r;
 GO

 -- 5.2. LEFT JOIN to the weekly interval table
 BEGIN
  DECLARE @startDate datetime = '1/1/2015', @endDate datetime = '2/1/2015';
  -- sample data 
  DECLARE @loans TABLE (loID INT, lockDate DATE);
  INSERT @loans SELECT r.rn, DATEADD(dd, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%32), @startDate)
  FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,50,1,1) r;

  -- solution 
  SELECT 
    WeekNbr   = r.RN,
    WeekStart = dt.WeekStart, 
    WeekEnd   = dt.WeekEnd,
    total     = COUNT(l.lockDate)
  FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,datediff(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate),7,1) r
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,r.N1,@StartDate) AS DATE), 
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,r.N2-1,@StartDate) AS DATE))) dt(WeekStart,WeekEnd)
  LEFT JOIN @loans l ON l.lockDate BETWEEN  dt.WeekStart AND dt.WeekEnd
  GROUP BY r.RN, dt.WeekStart, dt.WeekEnd ;
 END;

--===== 6. Identify the first vowel and last vowel in a along with their positions
 DECLARE @string VARCHAR(200) = 'This string has vowels';

 SELECT TOP(1) position = r.rn, letter = SUBSTRING(@string,r.rn,1)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,LEN(@string),1,1) r
 WHERE SUBSTRING(@string,r.rn,1) LIKE '%[aeiou]%'
 ORDER BY r.rn;

 -- To avoid a sort in the execution plan we'll use op instead of rn
 SELECT TOP(1) position = r.op, letter = SUBSTRING(@string,r.op,1)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,LEN(@string),1,1) r
 WHERE SUBSTRING(@string,r.rn,1) LIKE '%[aeiou]%'
 ORDER BY r.rn;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Revision History]:
 Rev 00 - 20140518 - Initial Development - Alan Burstein
 Rev 01 - 20151029 - Added 65 rows to make L1=465; 465^3=100.5M. Updated comment section
                   - Alan Burstein
 Rev 02 - 20180613 - Complete re-design including opposite number column (op)
 Rev 03 - 20180920 - Added additional CROSS JOIN to L2 for 530B rows max - Alan Burstein
****************************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
WITH L1(N) AS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM (VALUES
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0)) T(N) -- 90 values 
),
L2(N)  AS (SELECT 1 FROM L1 a CROSS JOIN L1 b CROSS JOIN L1 c),
iTally AS (SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM L2 a CROSS JOIN L2 b)
SELECT
  r.RN,
  r.OP,
  r.N1,
  r.N2
FROM
(
  SELECT
    RN = 0,
    OP = (@high-@low)/@gap,
    N1 = @low,
    N2 = @gap+@low
  WHERE @row1 = 0
  UNION ALL -- ISNULL required in the TOP statement below for error handling purposes
  SELECT TOP (ABS((ISNULL(@high,0)-ISNULL(@low,0))/ISNULL(@gap,0)+ISNULL(@row1,1)))
    RN = i.rn,
    OP = (@high-@low)/@gap+(2*@row1)-i.rn,
    N1 = (i.rn-@row1)*@gap+@low,
    N2 = (i.rn-(@row1-1))*@gap+@low
  FROM iTally AS i
  ORDER BY i.rn
) AS r
WHERE @high&@low&@gap&@row1 IS NOT NULL AND @high >= @low AND @gap > 0;
GO
```